# Why is my VS Code always opened with the default profile?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make vscode always open with a profile that I created but not the default one?

I imported the profile which I exported from my old PC, and I switch the File > Preferences > Profiles to the profile that I just imported.
At first it works fine, but after I close VS Code and open it up again with a new file, my vscode just opened with the default profile and there is no extensions and all font settings, color settings...etc. I have to switch the profile after I open VS Code evey single time.

I tried to find a way to set the profile I imported as default, but I didn't find that option.
And I also found that I can only delete those profiles that created or imported by me. I try to delete the default profile and only keep my own profile but it just doesn' work that way.

I also serched on google to find a way but all I can found is VS Code's official docs. And I didn't find what I want in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate your issue - reverting to the `Default` profile when re-opening vscode in the Stable build v1.76.

But **not** when testing in the Insiders Build v1.77.  So apparently that annoyance has been fixed.  And will probably be out in Stable v1.77 early April 2023.

Maybe as a result of reverting the behaviour reported here: [Opening a new folder should use the current profile](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171087).

Comment: Now I see! The version of vscode I installed is v1.76 and now I know why it happens. Hope they can brin taht behacviour back in the stable version! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 13):

You'll have to overwrite the Default profile with your new profile.

First export it as a JSON file. Then, open the exported file and Just change the value of the `"name"` attribute in the profile JSON to `"Default"`, then import the profile and confirm the overwrite prompt.

Please note that this will overwrite the original Default profile. The exported file can include or exclude any aspects of your user configuration, such as keybindings or extensions. For more information, please refer to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles).

Comment: That doesn't work any more - it says 'Profile with name Default already exists.'

Answer (score 5):

I use VSC both at home, for my personal projects and learning, and at my workplace. Both run on Windows machines, but I don't think that the peculiar Operating System leads to a loss of generality: the same can be applied to other OSes, as long as they use a graphical interface with icons. The home VSC uses the `Home` profile, whereas the work VSC uses the `Work` profile.

I have resorted to this simple workaround, based on [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_command-line), to launch the correct profile.

- When at home, the VSC icon on the desktop of my home PC will launch `"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --profile "Home"`
- When at work, the VSC icon on the desktop of my work laptop will launch `"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --profile "Work"`

This way, the procedure is fully automated by the desktop icon, and I don't have to worry about manually launching the correct profile.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my VS Code always opened with the default profile?

Because... it's the ***default*** profile :|

> So, is there a way to make vscode always open with a profile that I created but not the default one?

If you invoke `code --help`, you'll see:

> `--profile <profileName>` Opens the provided folder or workspace with the given profile and associates the profile with the workspace. If the profile does not exist, a new empty one is created. A folder or workspace must be provided for the profile to take effect.

From your described use-case, you may be interested in the following issue ticket: [Make it easy for users to import a profile as default #168867](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168867), and *maybe* this one: [Cannot set contributed profile as default #127573](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127573) (for profiles contributed by extensions). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above first issue ticket by googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues set profile as default -terminal`".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: I use two profiles on two different devices. To fix this issue, I use the command alias code='code --profile profile_name'. This allows me to open the application with my custom profile on each device.

this solution for unix based, you can install git bash for use in windows

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to load a different profile by default without using a command line parameter - `--profile <profileName>`. Instead the best you can currently do is override the default profile.

The new solution (as of January 2024) to replace the default profile is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168867#issuecomment-1913760854

```
For those looking for manual fix, here's what works as of Dec 2023:

Import your .code-profile file

Close VS Code

Go to ~/.config/Code/User/profiles/<profile id>

Copy keybindings.json and settings.json files and paste them to ~/.config/Code/User folder
Copy extensions.json and paste it to ~/.vscode/extensions folder
Open VS Code

Switch to Default profile

Delete your imported profile

This works on windows too, but the file locations are:
%AppData%\Roaming\Code\User (e.g. C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\Code\User) for ~/.config/Code/User
and
%HOMEPATH%\.vscode\extensions (e.g. C:\Users\MyUsername\.vscode\extensions) for ~/.vscode/extensions
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. the question is not asking how to make a non-default profile the actual default profile.