Automatically activating specific VS Code extensions for a particular folder
I'm looking for a way to ensure that only certain extensions are activated when Visual Studio Code is opened from a specific folder. My goals are:

Minimize bloat and improve performance
Ensure consistency across team members and future usage
Keep the codebase portable and reusable

I've considered a few options:

Profiles: Seems promising for managing extension sets
Local configurations: Possibly using a JSON file in the project folder
Workspaces: Not familiar with this, but it might be relevant

Ideally, I want a solution where:

Opening the folder automatically loads the correct profile or configuration
Only specified extensions are enabled; all others are disabled
Settings are stored locally with the project
It's easy for colleagues to adopt the same setup

Is there a recommended approach to achieve this? How can I set up VS Code to automatically use a specific configuration when opening a particular folder?

is this answered by any of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75678071/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76919221/11107541, or related questions?
